# Parallel executing of commands with pipe by GNU Parallel?

Tags: jq, gnu-parallel

Given a task with several commands combined by pipe:

`cat input/file1.json | jq '.responses[0] | {labelAnnotations: .labelAnnotations}' > output/file1.json`

Now, there are thousands of input JSON files, and I like to leverage GNU Parallel to parallelize all process. How could I do that? Something like this?

`parallel cat {} | jq '...' > output/{./} ::: input/*.json`

note: It gets even more complicated if there is a pipe inside `jq`'s filter...

Comment: Try quoting the `|` and the `<` by putting a backslash in front of each and use `parallel --dry-run ...` to see what it will do without doing anything.

Comment: Awesome! And what if there is pipe inside `jq`'s filter?

Comment: Your `jq` commands are inside single quotes already so they should be fine, I think.

Comment: Nope. It doesn't work. Got something like this `/bin/bash: {labelAnnotations:: command not found`

Comment: Can you swap the single quotes around your `jq` stuff for double quotes?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, it won't work, either.

Comment: If you're having troubles with specifying the jq filter, I'd suggest using the -f FILENAME command-line option of jq.  Also avoid cat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#QUOTING says:

> Conclusion: To avoid dealing with the quoting problems it may be easier just to write a small script or a function (remember to `export -f` the function) and have GNU parallel call that.

In your case it will look like this:

```
doit() {
  cat "$1" |
    jq '.responses[0] | {labelAnnotations: .labelAnnotations}' > "$2" 
}
export -f doit

parallel doit {} output/{/} ::: input/*.json
```

A nice thing about this is that you can test it:

```
doit input/foo1.json output/foo1.json
```

And when that works, parallelizing it is trivial.

If you have newer version of GNU Parallel this should work, too:

```
parallel --results output/{/} -q jq '.responses[0] | {labelAnnotations: .labelAnnotations}' ::: input/*.json
```

Comment: Thank you! I did solve this quoting challenges by writing a small script. Your sharing about `-q` and `--results` are awesome, too!

Comment: hmm I am having similar problem with no solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75268073/using-jq-and-gnu-parallel-together