# using jq and gnu parallel together

Tags: bash, jq, gnu-parallel

I have a `jq` command which I am trying to parallelise using `GNU parallel` but for some reason I am not able to get it to work.

The vanilla `jq` query is:

```
jq --raw-output '._id as $id | ._source.CitationTextHeader.Article.AuthorList[]? | .Affiliation.Affiliation | [ $id, .[0:rindex(" Electronic address:")] ] | @csv' results.json > test.out
```

I have tried to use it with `parallel` like so:

```
parallel -j0 --keep-order --spreadstdin "jq --raw-output '._id as $id | ._source.CitationTextHeader.Article.AuthorList[]? | .Affiliation.Affiliation | [ $id, .[0:rindex(" Electronic address:")] ] | @csv'" < results.json > test.json
```

but I get some bizzare compile error:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting '$' or '[' or '{' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
._id as  | ._source.CitationTextHeader.Article.AuthorList[]? | .Affiliation.Affiliation | [ , .[0:rindex( Electronic address:)] ] | @csv         
jq: 1 compile error
```

I think it does not like something re: quoting things in the string, but the error is a bit unhelpful.

*UPDATE*

Looking at other threads, I managed to construct this:

```
parallel -a results.json --results test.json -q jq -r '._id as $id | ._source.CitationTextHeader.Article.AuthorList[]? | .Affiliation.Affiliation | [ $id, .[0:rindex(" Electronic address:")] ] | @csv'
```

but now it complains:

```
parallel: Error: Command line too long (76224 >= 63664) at input 0:
```

:(

An aexample (firstline) of the json file:

```
{
  "_index": "corpuspm",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "6786777",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "CitationTextHeader": {
      "Article": {
        "AuthorList": [
          {
            "Affiliation": {
              "Affiliation": "title, society, American Pediatric Society. address@hotmail.com."
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `to parallelise` Over what? Files?

Comment: try escaping the innver dbl-quotes, i.e. `[0:rindex(\" Electronic address:\")] ] ` OR you may have to "shell-quoting" escape them like `"'"'"` . Good luck.

Comment: `parallel` doesn't just magically run your command on multiple cores, you have to provide how to split up the initial data into chunks, and based on that it can execute a provided subcommand in parallel working on those chunks individually. But you have to provide both the split, as well as the subcommand. We can help you formulate that subcommand with `jq` but you still have to provide on what chunks it should operate.

Comment: @pmf the command `jq --raw-output '._id as $id | ._source.CitationTextHeader.Article.AuthorList[]? | .Affiliation.Affiliation | [ $id, .[0:rindex(" Electronic address:")] ] | @csv' results.json > test.out
` runs on `results.json` which is a large file containing a json on each line. So, I presume `parallel` should operate on chunks of `results.json`. I dont really mind how it is chunked (single or batch)

Comment: Have you tried putting the filters into a file and using jq -f to shorten the command line?

Comment: How many lines (i.e., how many JSON entities) does the JSONLines file have? Unless there is a huge number, parallel isn't likely to help much.

Comment: Getting quoting right is hard (https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#quoting). It is usually easier to make a shell function and call that (https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_examples.html#example-calling-bash-functions). It also makes it easy to test that the function works as expected before using it with GNU Parallel.

Comment: GNU Parallel is line-oriented. So it can be a bit tricky to make it work with JSON. If each JSON object is on a single line, then it should not be too hard to get it working. May I suggest you show us the first 3 lines of `results.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more info this will be a guess:

```
doit() {
  jq --raw-output '._id as $id | ._source.CitationTextHeader.Article.AuthorList[]? | .Affiliation.Affiliation | [ $id, .[0:rindex(" Electronic address:")] ] | @csv'
}
export -f doit
cat results.json | parallel --pipe doit > test.out
```

It reads blocks of ~1 MB from `results.json` which it passes to `doit`.

If that works, you may be able to speed up the processing with:

```
parallel --block -1 -a results.json --pipepart doit > test.out
```

It will on-the-fly split up `results.json` into n parts (where n = number of CPU threads). Each part will be piped into `doit`. The overhead of this is quite small.

Add `--keep-order` if you need the output to be in the same order as input.

If your disks are slow and your CPU is fast, this may be even faster:

```
parallel --lb --block -1 -a results.json --pipepart doit > test.out
```

It will buffer in RAM instead of in tempfiles. `--keep-order` will, however, not be useful here because the output from job 2 will only be read after job 1 is done.

Answer (score 2):

> `results.json` is a large file containing a json on each line

You could use `--spreadstdin` and `-n1` to linewise spread the input into your `jq` filter. Without knowing about the structure of your input JSONs, I have just copied over your "vanilla" filter:

```bash
< results.json > test.out parallel -j0 -n1 -k --spreadstdin 'jq -r '\''
  ._id as $id | ._source.CitationTextHeader.Article.AuthorList[]?
  | .Affiliation.Affiliation | [$id, .[0:rindex(" Electronic address:")]]
  | @csv
'\'
```

Comment: I get `/usr/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/usr/bin/bash: -c: line 1: `jq -r ._id as $id | ._source.CitationTextHeader.Article.AuthorList[]? | .Affiliation.Affiliation | [$id, .[0:rindex(" Electronic address:")]] | @csv'`. When i try escaping it, I get a bunch of other errors.

Comment: @AJW Fixed the quoting.

Comment: its literally doing nothing.. just hangs... :( no error either and nothing is on the output file.. the command does not end either

Comment: @AJW Can you check the CPU load, especially the amount of busy cores?

Comment: i see only a single core being used when i look at htop :(

Comment: @AJW Hm, try changing `-n1` to `-n0` (or omit it entirely)

Comment: same result unfortunately :((

Comment: I have added to the question the first line of json as an example

Comment: @AJW Your sample line in the original file is in one line, right? (Meaning, you have pretty-printed it into multiple lines just for the sake of readability in the question). I have compacted the sample back into one line, and duplicated it 1 million times. Running the vanilla filter on that file takes 1.055 seconds, running the parallel version runs in 0.687 seconds. So, I guess, it works on my machine...

Comment: yes, what you have done it correct. Thats bizzare...

Comment: I get a few warnings: `parallel: Warning: Only enough file handles to run 252 jobs in parallel.
parallel: Warning: Try running 'parallel -j0 -N 252 --pipe parallel -j0'
parallel: Warning: or increasing 'ulimit -n' (try: ulimit -n `ulimit -Hn`)
parallel: Warning: or increasing 'nofile' in /etc/security/limits.conf
parallel: Warning: or increasing /proc/sys/fs/file-max
parallel: Warning: No more file handles.

Comment: @AJW I can only upscale your single input line sample, and that runs without any issues. So, I guess I can't reproduce your error...

Comment: So are you way past the original error about shell quoting? If you expected that to work and have only moved on, realize that if you `echo "jq --raw-output '._id as $id | ._source.CitationTextHeader.Article.AuthorList[]? | .Affiliation.Affiliation | [ $id, .[0:rindex(" Electronic address:")] ] | @csv'"`, the output will not have the dbl-quotes you need around `"Electronic address"`. Which seems to match with the first eror message. Good luck!

Comment: The double quotes around that string are essential for jq. Without them, jq would error out. That's why I used single quotes around the whole argument (the jq call), escaped the inner pair of single quotes around the jq filter, so that any double quotes and dollar signs can happily thrive inside. Compare to the output of `echo 'jq -r '\''._id as $id | ._source.CitationTextHeader.Article.AuthorList[]? | .Affiliation.Affiliation | [$id, .[0:rindex(" Electronic address:")]] | @csv'\'`.

Comment: *"The double quotes around that string are essential for jq"* . Yes, I understand that. I am pointing out to you you either need `\"` or  `"'"'"` nested quoting OR heavan forbid, something even more nested because multiple parsers are parsing your cmd line. Good luck.